# Add custom operations Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to add a new operation on Spark SQL, I have already used user defined function of the form

```
dataframe.filter(udf("$a", "$b"))
```

I need to add a similar function but operating on two dataFrames, for example adding a function like:

```
dataframe1.udf(dataframe2))
```

To be more precise, the function is an optimized join on two dataframes.

The actual code is

```
CustomJoin(dataframe1,dataframe2)
```

Is this possible using user defined functions? Any other solutions or examples?

Comment: can you be more specific in what you exactly want to do?

Comment: Apparently, reading the link. this is not possible. I want to write a custom join. Actually, the code works like this `CustomJoin(df1,df2)`. My objective is to change it like this `df1.CustomJoin(df2)`

Comment: Can you please provide example data, code and expected output? As of now your question is still too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use implicit for this:

```
 class AugmentedDataFrame(val df: DataFrame) {
    def CustomJoin(df2: Dataframe){ ......}
 }

 object DataFrameImplicits {
   implicit def dfToAugmentedDataFrame(df: DataFrame) = new AugmentedDataFrame(df)
 }
```

and then:

```
 import DataFrameImplicits._
 df.CustomJoin(df2)
```

to learn more how using implicit to add a custom methods to an existing class :
[Add Your Own Methods to the String Class](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch01s11.html)

Comment: can you explain more your solution? why I need to use implicits in this case.

Comment: I added a link to learn more about the use of implicit in your case

Comment: You answer works perfectly. Do you know if there is a way to extend this using SQL `Select * from t1 CustomJoin t2`

Comment: i think it's not possible, because the sql query is interpreted and transformed to queryExecution by spark core